# Prove that the zero square matrices are the only matrices that are both symmetric and skew-symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, symmetric-matrices

> Prove that the zero square matrices are the only matrices that are both symmetric and skew-symmetric.

**My Proof**

I will restate the proposition in a way that makes the proof easier to formulate:

> There exists a unique matrix $A = 0_{n \times n}$, such that it is both symmetric and skew-symmetric.

1. We first prove that the object exists.

$A = 0_{n \times n} = [a_{ij}]_{n \times n} = 0 \ \forall i,j$

$\implies -A = -[a_{ij}]_{n \times n}$ *By the properties of scalar multiplication of matrices.*

$\implies (-A)^T = -(A)^T = -[a_{ji}]_{n \times n}$ *By the properties and definition of matrix transposition.*

$= -0 \ \forall j,i$ *By the definition of the zero matrix.*

$= 0 = A$

and

$A^T = [a_{ji}]_{n \times n} = 0 \ \forall j,i$ *By the definition of the zero matrix.*

$= A$

$Q.E.D.$

2. We must now prove that $A$ is unique.

$A = A^T = (-A)^T$

Let $B = B^T = (-B)^T$

We want to prove that $A = B$.

We now have $A = (-A)^T, A = A^T, B = (-B)^T, B = B^T$

Adding $A = (-A)^T, A = A^T$ and $B = (-B)^T, B = B^T$, we get

$2A = A^T + (-A)^T$ and $2B = B^T + (-B)^T$

$\implies A = \dfrac{1}{2}(A^T) + \dfrac{1}{2}(-A)^T$

and

$B = \dfrac{1}{2}(B^T) + \dfrac{1}{2}(-A)^T$

$A - B = \dfrac{1}{2}(A^T) + \dfrac{1}{2}(-A^T) - \dfrac{1}{2}(B^T) - \dfrac{1}{2}(-B^T)$

$= \dfrac{1}{2}(A^T) - \dfrac{1}{2}(A^T) - \dfrac{1}{2}(B^T) + \dfrac{1}{2}(B^T)$ *Using the hypothesis.*

$= 0$

$\implies A = B$

$Q.E.D.$

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my proof for correctness and provide feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assume neither $A$ nor $B$ is zero in the second part. For this part, if $A$ is both symmetric and skew symmetric, then $A=(A^{T})^{T}=(-A)^{T}=-A^{T}=-A$, so $2A=0$, then $A=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't see why I cannot assume this; the assumption that $A$ is the zero matrix is part of the hypothesis, and so it is assumed by definition?

Comment: The assumption does not say that, rather, it means partly that, if $A$ is both symmetric and skew symmetric, prove that $A=0$, this is the keyword "the only".

Comment: Hmm. I'm interpreting it conversely; namely that, If we have a zero square matrix, then the matrix is both symmetric and skew-symmetric. Therefore, the assumption would be that we have a zero square matrix (in this case, $A$), and we must prove the conclusion that it is both symmetric and skew-symmetric. Can anyone else please clarify this?

Comment: Actually there are two parts: First, show that the zero matrix fulfils the condition. Second, show that if any matrix $A$ satisfies the condition, then $A$ is the zero matrix.

Comment: So you're saying that the uniqueness part of my proof is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to say.

Comment: The method I used is the "direct uniqueness method" from page 127 of *How to Read and Do Proofs* by Daniel Solow: "With the direct uniqueness method, you assume that there are two objects having the certain property and for which the something happens. If there really is only one such object then, using the two objects with their certain properties, the something that happens, and the information in $A$ (the hypothesis), you must conclude that the two objects are one and the same -- that is, that they are equal." This is what I did with $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Yes, so one unknown object is $A$ which satisfies the condition, and the other is the fixed object, the zero matrix, which satisfies the condition as well, and you conclude that the object $A$ is actually the zero matrix.

Comment: But this is not in accordance with what Solow said in my quote; in fact, he explicitly says to assume that there are two identical objects, and then to prove that these objects are actually the same object. That's what I did with $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by two identical objects, then prove that they are actually the same? Isn't that "identical" means "the same"?

Comment: He means two objects with identical properties. Then show that those two objects are actually the same object.

Comment: Okay, let's look, if you assume two objects, $A$, $B$, which both satisfy the condition, then you manage to argue that $A=B$, what does this really tell you? Almost nothing, because you know nothing about $A$, plus, does $A$ must be the zero matrix then? Surely not always.

Comment: Why would you assume that both $A$ and $B$ are zero matrices, if you do this assumption, then $A$ is zero matrix, nothing to prove.

Comment: Ok, I think you're correct. I have updated the uniqueness proof. I have used the fact that every square matrix can be expressed uniquely as the sum of a symmetric matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix. Although one could shorten the second proof significantly, I made it longer to emphasise the aforementioned fact. How does it look? Up-voted for the significant help you've provided.

Comment: Yes, as I have said, you just proved that $A=B$, now the only thing is to show that $A=B=0$. But this is almost clear, since the zero matrix satisfies the symmetry and skew-symmetry properties, so the zero matrix can be the candidate of the so called $B$, so $A=0$.

Comment: Now I know why you were confused. If the question says that, prove that the matrix which satisfies the condition of being symmetry and skew-symmetry is unique (so how does the matrix look like? We simply have no idea by just this kind of uniqueness), then your reasoning works. But now the question indicates particularly that it is unique and it is the zero matrix, so at the final stage you need to realise either $A$ or $B$ to be the zero matrix.

Comment: Ahh, now I see why you structured your proof in such a way.